Local audio file can not play
My implementation:
Future<void> _playSound() async {
  await _audioPlayer.play(AssetSource('audio.mp3'));
}

How I addressed the file in pubspec.yaml:
assets:
    - assets/audio.mp3


I get this error:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      getTemporaryDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:55:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AudioCache.getTempDir (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:76:41)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AudioCache.fetchToMemory (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:91:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AudioCache.load (package:audioplayers/src/audio_cache.dart:114:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      AudioPlayer.setSourceAsset (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:337:17)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      AudioPlayer.setSource (package:audioplayers/src/audioplayer.dart:284:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      AudioPlayer.play (package:audioplayers/src/audiopl<…>

I've already restarted the app, I did flutter clean and after flutter pub get.
What's the problem?

What is a use of path_provider package?

Make sure you're calling WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() before any other plugin initializations.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart'; // is this imported correctly?

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}


Also, make sure your pubspec.yaml is correct in terms of indentation:
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/audio.mp3


added, but still error(

what about completely stopping the app in the terminal and restarting after fetching the dependencies? Run flutter clean to clear the build cache, then flutter pub get to fetch dependencies, then restart the app using flutter run.
I'd check pubspec.yaml too for possible indentation problems.
